# How to concatenate variables into SQL strings

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to concatenate a variable table name into my SQL query such as the following...

```
ALTER FUNCTION fn_myfunction(@KeyValue text)
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO @tmpTbl1
     SELECT @KeyValue AS fld1
     FROM tbl + @KeyValue + KeyValue.fld1
```

I also attempted the following but it told me I had to declare the table variable?

```
ALTER FUNCTION fn_myfunction(@KeyValue text, @KeyTable text)
     FROM @KeyTable.fld1
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can accomplish this (if I understand what you are trying to do) using dynamic SQL.

The trick is that you need to create a string containing the SQL statement. That's because the tablename has to specified in the actual SQL text, when you execute the statement. The table references and column references can't be supplied as parameters, those have to appear in the SQL text.

So you can use something like this approach:

```
SET @stmt = 'INSERT INTO @tmpTbl1 SELECT ' + @KeyValue 
    + ' AS fld1 FROM tbl' + @KeyValue

EXEC (@stmt)
```

First, we create a SQL statement as a string. Given a @KeyValue of 'Foo', that would create a string containing:

```
'INSERT INTO @tmpTbl1 SELECT Foo AS fld1 FROM tblFoo'
```

At this point, it's just a string. But we can execute the contents of the string, as a dynamic SQL statement, using `EXECUTE` (or `EXEC` for short).

The old-school `sp_executesql` procedure is an alternative to EXEC, another way to execute dymamic SQL, which also allows you to pass parameters, rather than specifying all values as literals in the text of the statement.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

EBarr points out (correctly and importantly) that this approach is susceptible to SQL Injection.

Consider what would happen if `@KeyValue` contained the string:

```
'1 AS foo; DROP TABLE students; -- '
```

The string we would produce as a SQL statement would be:

```
'INSERT INTO @tmpTbl1 SELECT 1 AS foo; DROP TABLE students; -- AS fld1 ...'
```

When we EXECUTE that string as a SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO @tmpTbl1 SELECT 1 AS foo;
DROP TABLE students;
-- AS fld1 FROM tbl1 AS foo; DROP ...
```

And it's not just a DROP TABLE that could be injected. Any SQL could be injected, and it might be much more subtle and even more nefarious. (The first attacks can be attempts to retreive information about tables and columns, followed by attempts to retrieve data (email addresses, account numbers, etc.)

One way to address this vulnerability is to validate the contents of @KeyValue, say it should contain only alphabetic and numeric characters (e.g. check for any characters not in those ranges using `LIKE '%[^A-Za-z0-9]%'`. If an illegal character is found, then reject the value, and exit without executing any SQL.

Comment: This is likely the right/best solution given the requirements.  Nevertheless, it should be noted that this is an easy path for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: I left off the "+ KeyValue.fld1" from my answer, because it wasn't clear if that was meant to be part of the tablename. (It would have been concatenated, but then the tablename would contain a period, and while it would be valid (if the tablename were enclosed in square brackets), that would be highly irregular.

Answer (score 7):

You could make use of `Prepared Stements` like this.

```
set @query = concat( "select name from " );
set @query = concat( "table_name"," [where condition] " );

prepare stmt from @like_q;
execute stmt;
```

Comment: Is "@like_q" meant to be "@query" here? Are you meant to be over-writing the value of "@query"?

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.