# How to declare a SQL Variable that updates with the date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, getdate

I'm writing a stored proc and would like to generate a string name that updates with the date. For example, since today is July 21st, 2017, I'd like the string variable to be `Today_is_20170721`.

Here is what I've tried so far, based on [an answer to a question similar to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17754288/3856609):

```
SET @datestring = 'INSERT INTO @tmpTbl1 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)'
EXEC (@datestring)

@desiredstring = 'Today_is_' + @datestring
```

I kept getting the error `Must declare the scalar variable variable "@datestring".`

From where, I'm not sure where to go- I'm fairly certain my variable is declared.

Comment: What?  I don't get it.  What is "a string name that updates with the date"?  Is this a column in the table?  Is this the name of a variable?  It looks like a value.  Why are you using dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 3):

It occurs to me that you might want:

```
declare @desiredstring varchar(255);

set @desiredstring = 'Today_is_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112);
```

However, this is pretty simple SQL code so it might not be what you really want.

Comment: That is exactly what I'd like, but even that snippet of code returns an error: "Incorrect syntax near '@desiredstring'."

Comment: @daOnlyBG . . . Needs a `set`.

Comment: Excellent- thanks. I believe Santi above is correct in specifying that I didn't use a `declare` statement.

Comment: Or just use `'Today_is_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112);` wherever you intend to use @desiredString